# Can this slow running VB.Net code be improved in any way?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, performance, .net-4.0

I have the code below running in my application and it takes approx 2 - 6 seconds to run, on average it is around 3-4 seconds. I know that the stored procedure executes way under a second so the problem must be with my VB.Net code. Is there anything I can do to this to improve performance at all?

So far I have sped it up slightly by making my stored proc return some of the HTML ready to be inserted into each element rather than having multiple IF statements within the loop, and I changed the loop to a While rather than for each which has helped slightly. I am assuming that some of the performance problems may be down to the server but I would also like to know if there is anything in my code that could be improved.

Thanks

```
   Private Sub dbGetOpenUnassignedTickets()

      ' Here we need to get the results of the query
      Dim Events As New DataTable()

      Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Blueprint").ToString())

      Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
      cmd.CommandText = "spGetUnassignedTickets"

      cmd.Connection = conn

      Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
         conn.Open()
         da.Fill(Events)
         conn.Close()
      End Using

      Dim TicketHTML As String = String.Empty
      Dim counter As Integer = 0
      While (counter < Events.Rows.Count - 1)

         Dim strDragDrop As String

         strDragDrop = "onmousedown='return DayPilotCalendar.dragStart(this.parentNode, 60*30, """ & Events.Rows(counter)("TicketID") & """, ""EE"");'"

         'IF Current user <> looking at their own schedule AND not allowed to assign tickets
         If (Session("UserID") <> ddlUser.SelectedValue And Session("AssignTickets") = 0) Then
            strDragDrop = String.Empty
         End If

         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + Events.Rows(counter)("SeverityHTML")

         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + "<table width='100%' " + strDragDrop + ">"

         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + Events.Rows(counter)("TypeHTML")

         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + Events.Rows(counter)("ProductHTML")

         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + "<tr>"
         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + "<td colspan='2'><b>Description</b> <br />" + Events.Rows(counter)("DescriptionHTML") + "</td>"

         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + "</tr>"

         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + "<tr>"
         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + "<td>"
         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + "<b>Logged Date:</b>"
         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + "</td>"
         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + "<td align='left'>"
         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + Events.Rows(counter)("LogDate")
         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + "</td>"
         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + "</tr>"

         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + "</table>"
         TicketHTML = TicketHTML + "</div>"

         counter = counter + 1

      End While

      ' And now update the inner HTML of the thing we are putting the tickets into
      divTickets.InnerHtml = TicketHTML

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you use [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx#Y3583) for data retrieval and [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for building your HTML.

You can also alter or make a new version of `spGetUnassignedTickets` that only return the columns needed.

Comment: Thanks Rick StringBuilder was the solution. It runs pretty much instantly now, unfortunately I cant actually edit the stored proc to return less columns as it needs all the ones it returns

Answer (score 1):

Change **TicketHTML** to stringbuilder to speed up the string part

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested a StringBuilder will give you a great speed increase (especially if you're using a lot of records).

I'd also loop the rows with `For Each dr As DataRow in Events.Rows` and then say `dr("TypeHtml")` instead of `Events.Rows(counter)("TypeHTML")` etc...

Comment: I had the loop as a foreach exactly how you suggest but strangely the while loop was faster. Now I have used a stringbuilder I will probably try put the loop back to a foreach and see if it impacts the performance at all

Comment: @Purplegoldfish Interesting - I would just have thought that accessing `Events.Rows(counter)` repeatedly would be slower than having a reference available in the loop ie `dr`. But StringBuilder will definitely give you an improvement especially if you're making a very large string. [Have a look at this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html)

Comment: I would have thought the for each loop faster too, at the moment it does load so fast that performance either way is not really an issue but I will deffinately be trying the for each loop again even if just for my own curiosity. Thanks for the article, I was just doing some googling about why stringbuilder was faster